# using option and arguments together in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, global-variables

Im trying to learn bash script and Im playing around with a program.

I have a main program looking something like this:

```
while (( $# ))
do
    case "$1" in

        --help | -h)
            usage
            exit 0
        ;;

        --version | -v)
            version
            exit 0
        ;;

        funcone        \
        | functwo      \
        | functhree     )
            command=$1
            shift
            app-"$command" "$@"
            exit 0
        ;;

        *)
            badUsage "Option/command not recognized."   
            exit 1
        ;;

    esac
done

badUsage
exit 1
```

Now I want to be able to add an option --save so that the data Iam fetching from the other functions (using curl) is saved to a file.

How can I write in my main program so that when the option --save is added to the command line, the data from the functions get saved to a file  but if --save is not in the command line, the functions get executed like normal, like in the code example.

Maybe I can use like a global variable to set to true when --save is there, but I dont know how to write for both the option and argument to be executed

Comment: maye use some option/argument parsing tools, such as `getops`?

Comment: Just use a flag variable: Set it to 0 before entering the loop, and set it to 1 once you have encountered the `save` argument. This is nothing specific to bash: You would probably do the same in any other programming language.